# How to draw text boxes that segment vertically and horizontally, but which can cross the borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

Below is a picture of some text divided into columns and rows.  Importantly, rows span across the vertical dividing line even though the text is not allowed to cross this boundary.  I'd like to try to produce something like this in a HTML page.

[image]

To describe how this is typically drawn, there are always two columns that take up approximately the width of the screen.  Each row has a block of text in the left and one in the right, and has a bounding box that spans across the two columns.

But because there are these "subproofs" (in the picture, this is lines 2 through 4) this cannot be accomplished by just a table.  (Or if it can, I'm not familiar with the ability of tables to do this.) A subproof is an extra bounding box that spans a collection of rows, giving it added indentation on those rows, and an extra border.

I've tried simulating this with tables, grids, flexboxes, but I haven't found a way to create something like this.  Tables don't seem to have the ability to make "subtables" like this, where certain rows and columns are specified to give extra border lines and indentation.  Grids and flexboxes don't seem to allow overlapping boxes such that the text does not cross the boundaries.  Of course I could be wrong about all of that, and I'd be happy to be corrected.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. I am not sure if an elegant HTML/CSS-only solution exists. So my first impression would be to start playing with absolutely positioned DIVs for the borders and the contents, thus creating custom JavaScript-driven layout logic. Creating a PoC is tempting, but sadly I do not have the time now. I think it would be useful to know if there is a theoretical or practical limit on the depth of the nesting of such subproofs and how the border drawing layout and the available space for the text content should be dynamically adjusted to that nesting depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to fake this effect.

For example, on the box with the "4. Q", you could try to make a div element with a border. The div would be positioned to be aligned on the top right of its parent. If you copy this method for each box of the "sub-table", I'm sure you could create something.

It still wont be a "real table" though.